# Cross-platform builds with OGRE3D via CMake. Any tips?

Tags: ogre, cross-platform

I've been trying to compile a simple project for both OSX and Windows platforms, using OGRE3D, but I've got some problems on the way.

I'm using CMake to create my platform specific project files (VS solution & Xcode project). Some problems I found are:

- OGRE3D source is distributed in 2 flavors, Windows sources and UNIX/OSX sources.
- In OSX, compiling dependencies (freetype, FreeImage and specially OIS) is such a pain.
- I don't know how to handle precompiled dependencies (they exist for both Win & Mac).

May sound like a noob question, but I would appreciate some tips on this. Resources, forum posts, anything. There exists any "cross-platform base project for OGRE3D" on the net?
Would be really helpful if someone who already managed to do this can bring some light.

Btw, I'm not basing the project on OGRE3D, it's just that is the biggest library I'm probably using, so I depend a lot on it.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just linking in the binaries for each platform?  I'm fairly sure that Ogre has precompiled binaries for those two platforms.

Comment: I want to, but I can't figure out a way to make everything work with CMake. Do you know if someone has any CMake script relative to this task that could help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

CMake should take care of everything once it's completely configured and found the precompiled dependencies.

Ogre's CMake system will look for the dependencies when run to generate the project files to build the library. If the dependencies are not installed (see [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Prerequisites&tikiversion=Mac%20OS%20X%20&%20iOS)) you can specify where the precompiled dependencies are to be found in the flags from the CMakeGUI (I don't remember exactly and can't check right now, sorry). They will end with INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR and there will appear the dependency name BOOST, TBB, POCO, DEVIL...

[Here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Prerequisites&tikiversion=Mac%20OS%20X%20&%20iOS) you will find the rest of the instructions to build the latest Ogre in OSX.

Hope it helps you.